# Jvectormap overlaping regions, bring region to top, z-index?

Tags: javascript, css, jvectormap

[a busy cat http://shrani.si/f/2Z/13K/3VqfQ1Ph/rmp.jpg](http://shrani.si/f/2Z/13K/3VqfQ1Ph/rmp.jpg)
![no image][1]

Here , the blue, is region that I created in inkscape.
Below is what displays jvectormap in browser, cursor beeing where 'testni1' text is. It looks it is behind of all other regions.

The A2 path which is blue region, I putted it on top of jvectormap file list of regions, or at bottom, thinking that will bring it to top, but it does not. It stays behind.

How to bring it to top ?

```
  "paths": 
{
    "AT-2": {"path": "m 272.39276,333.19565 153.50948,0 c 43.2173,30.28397 86.00383,60.63807 0,111.95804 l -153.50948,0 z",
             "name": "testni1"},
    "AT-3": {"path": "m 182.62865
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not fresh, but I had the same problem and maybe somebody else stumbles over this.
I came up with the solution to simply re-add the svg-path in question.
jQuery will remove the path from it's current place in the DOM and append it again at the end, which puts it on top of the others.

I needed to bring the region to the top on mouseover, so here goes:

When setting up the map, put in "onRegionOver":

```
onRegionOver: function(e, code)
{  
    var path    = $('path[data-code="'+code+'"]').get(0);
    var pathParent  = $('path[data-code="'+code+'"]').parent();

    $(pathParent).append(path);
},
```

That's it. Hope, this helps.